# Failed to proper setup php + mysql + phpmyadminon iis ? what going on?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Failed to proper setup php + mysql + phpmyadmin on iis ? what going on ? one OK the rest not OK ?

I tried most solution but still could not solve these this issues :-

**1.**

```
Bzip2 compression and decompression requires functions (bzopen, bzcompress) which are unavailable on this system.
```

**2.**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...                OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
                                 General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
                                          Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
                                          Creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
                                Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
                                    Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
                                      Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...          not OK [ Documentation ]
                                               SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
                                                  Designer: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
                                                  Tracking: Disabled
```

**3.**

```
Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

**4.**

```
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.10.  This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

---

*Downloaded libmcrypt.dll and copied to C:\Windows\System32*

Because of reach Text limit, i upload the text of php.ini and config.inc.php, can you guy please help me check where is the problem ? Thx a lot =D Php.ini and config.inc.php posted with html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a whole bunch of PHP extensions.  Simply uncomment the required extensions in your PHP.ini.  If you are missing extensions, either download a PHP distribution that includes them, or Google around for the individual extension binaries for Windows.  (They are scattered about.)

Comment: i googled but no result of binary, is the problem 2 and 4 also bringing out by this issue ?

Comment: @Brad you try to check my php.ini for correctness, please... i think i was done what you mean ~

Comment: I don't think issue #4 is a major issue.  For issue #3, you are probably missing a couple of the files mcrypt needs.  Can you post the output of your `phpinfo()` somewhere?

Comment: I think you are editing the wrong PHP.ini.  For example, in the php.ini you posted, there is this directive:  `extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"`  When I check your phpinfo(), I see that the extension path is actually `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.2\ext\`  In any case, mcrypt isn't being loaded, or it would show up in phpinfo().

Comment: You should leave those problems in your question and mark how you solved them, so others can find this and refer to it later.  Regarding the problems that are still left, these are okay.  You don't need them.  If you want to use them, refer to the documentation links provided.  See http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/what-are-general-relation-features-and-linked-tables-in-phpmyadmin-123561.html

Comment: @brad , yea...you're right ^^ recover it already and thx for remind...now all of my problem solved : half year ago i installed wordpress on my iis with web installer...i don't know there is the PHP running and mine fresh downloaded c:\php is not called up, additional, the not ok and ok thing, i done with delete the old mysql and re-execute the script of creating table to new installed database =D