# use php-cpp error: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, c++, php-cpp

I successfully compiled the [EmptyExtension](http://www.php-cpp.com/EmptyExtension.tar.gz) and got salamander_php.so(my extension name).
Then I copied it to the php extension_dir and added the row to the php.ini

`extension=salamander_php.so`

when I input `php -v` I got the warning

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php7.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303/salamander_php.so' - /lib/libphpcpp.so.2.0: 
undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have compiled your extension for either the wrong version of PHP or the bits don't match; x86 vs x64.

Comment: I am certainly no expert on extensions but maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/25800203/2191572 and https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/151 for clues.